# Ionic which is faster ng-click or on-tap

Tags: ionic-framework

Which is faster in Ionic on a mobile device on-tap or ng-click. To me they seem pretty similar however onClick is much slower.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/StevenIseki/pen/qxvpK)

```
<button class="button button-light button-dark" on-tap="onTap()">tap</button>
<button class="button button-light button-dark" ng-click="onClick()">click</button>
```

Comment: Read this: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both should be pretty equal, because a tap can only be determined based on how long the touch event occurs. I did something like this below and had the methods console.log when they fired the callback. I see the tap is going first, but click is happening at the same time in my test.

```
<button class="button" on-tap="onTap()" ng-click="onClick()">Hit me</button>
```